# Mobile test automation tool selection for iOS

Tags: ios, automation

We are currently evaluating the mobile test automation tools for our reputed client. So far we have discovered that the following tools are popular. We want to perform POC of one open source and one licensed tool and perform the comparison study in terms of the best fitment to the client requirements. The client used iOS bid time.

Please let me know the Pros and Cons of each tool documented below and provide the recommendation. Based on your inputs, we will go ahead and perform the POC. The applications to be automated are enterprise applications. This is the first time we are doing the Mobile test automation, so please excuse if this question is too basic in nature.

List of tools we are aware of:

1. ZAP-Fix
2. Egg plant
3. M-eux
4. Fonemonkey

Appreciate all your inputs / assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better is to take a look at [Frank](https://github.com/moredip/Frank) or [Calabash](https://github.com/calabash)